# Google apps script html script tag length limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-apps-script

I've tried to integrate react with google apps script.
I created react app called "example" and I have empty CSS and these scripts:

index.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
root.render(element);
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I also created script called migrateGAS.js:

```js
import * as fs from "fs";

const clArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
let args = {};
for (let i = 0; i < clArgs.length; i+=2) {
    args[clArgs[i]] = clArgs[i+1];
}

const path = args["-bp"] || "./";
const filename = args["-fn"] || "index";

const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${path}/build/asset-manifest.json`));

fs.readFile(`${path}build/${filename}.html`, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    let new_val = data.toString()
        .replace(/<script.*><\/script>/, "")
        .replace("</body>", `<?!= require('${filename}.js.html') ?></body>`)
        .replace(/<link.*rel="stylesheet">/, `<?!= require('${filename}.css.html') ?>`);

    fs.writeFile(`./clasp/${filename}.html`, new_val, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});

const format_dict = {
    "css": "style",
    "js": "script"
};
json.entrypoints.forEach(i => {
    let format = i.match(/.*\.(css|js)$/m)[1];

    fs.readFile(`${path}build/${i}`, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let new_val = `<${format_dict[format]}>${data.toString()}</${format_dict[format]}>`;

        fs.writeFile(`./clasp/${filename}.${format}.html`, new_val, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    })
});
```

I would run `npm run build` and then `node migrateGAS.js -bp ./example/` which will create files that can be served in google apps script:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= require('index.css.html') ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <?!= require('index.js.html') ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Script in GAS looks like this:

```js
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("test")
    .addItem("show menu", "sidebar")
    .addToUi();
}

function sidebar() {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index.html").evaluate();
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function require(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Now, if I open the sidebar it evaluates the HTML almost fine. But the script gets cut off like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl4it.png) and the page content does not appear.

I tried copying the script and running it locally and it works fine, so is there a limit on how long a script can be in google apps script?

I am thinking about just using babel and preprocessor like in [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project) tutorial. Is it better to use it like this?

Comment: I wouldn't go for GAS unless extremely necessary. It has several limitations and obscure things that happen... BTW what your print of script cutted off is just something DevTools does. I dont think it is actually cutted

Comment: DevTools probably do it (it happens in the local file). But the elements (heading "Hello, world") aren't displayed in the sidebar. As for GAS, I'd like to make an addon, so I don't think there's an alternative.

Comment: No such restriction that I know of. Your issue is unclear though. If I have to guess, your raw `replace`s on the html/js missed out some `<>`s.

Comment: As I said, copy/pasting it locally worked.

Comment: I tried adding `console.log("start")` at the start of the js and `console.log("end")` at the end. It works locally, in GAS sidebar it doesn't even log. Maybe the `require` function does something with it?

Answer (score 0):

Indenting the closing script tag in the converted script worked. I guess it had a problem with the comment at the end.

The second part of my original question is still unanswered: is it better to use babel and preprocessor or this setup?